# Professional Windows 7 icon packs

Tags: windows-7, icons

First of all, I know that there are some topics about icon packs here on stackoverflow.
However I'm looking for specific Windows 7 style icons.

Most icon packs that you find have a rather old look, or non natural Windows 7 look or too futuristic, catchy, kiddy, non professional.

I came across these:

http://www.iconshock.com

( http://www.iconshock.com/icon-collections/toolbar-icons-FULL%20WINDOWS%207%20+%20vector.html )

http://www.iconexperience.com/v_collections/

http://iconfactory.com/stockicons

http://glyfx.com/shop/

Are there any icon packs (that meet the Windows 7 requirements (all sizes, angle of the drawn icon, etc...) and **that look professional** or rather similar to **Windows 7**?

Comment: "or rather similar to Windows 7"

sorry didn't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a look at the ones that come in the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx) that are included with VS2010? I don't have access to it right now but it's supposed to be icons from Windows & Office etc so I assume they should meet the official requirements (though it might be older versions of the icons I suppose).

Comment: Yes but they don't have all the "needed" images and if I need an image they don't provide it with all sizes.